# Spark master not reachable after setting spark.network.crypto.enabled=true

Tags: apache-spark, security, encryption, pyspark

Through my experiments with Apache Spark I set up a standalone Spark cluster with 10 nodes, each reachable from each other.
I ran some pyspark scripts for local computations and experimented with spark-submit for multi-node executions. After that I wanted to see how security features can be set with spark-submit.
Hardly I was able to start with spark-submit jobs by setting `spark.authenenticate` and `spark.authenticate.secret` in the spark-defaults.conf file on every node in the cluster. But after, when the `spark.network.crypto.enabled` property was set, spark jobs crashed with error:

"StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up."

Could anyone help me to work around this problem and get Spark working with this property set, so I can try how the system works using not only authentication but encryption on RPC communication between nodes?